# Classe do pagseguro não funciona com CNPJ.

Tags: php, api

Estava com um problema ao realizar pagamentos usando a classe fornecida pelo pagseguro e cnpj. 
Toda vez que tentava realizar o pagamento, dava o seguinte erro:

```
HTTP 400 - BAD_REQUEST [THE REQUEST CANNOT BE FULFILLED DUE TO BAD SYNTAX]
11164 - senderCPF invalid value:...
```

Mesmo alterando o tipo do documento pra CNPJ, o erro persistia com o senderCPF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Descobri que isso é uma falha na classe do pagseguro. A correção é muito simples.
Abra o arquivo PagSeguroPaymentParser.class.php e vá na linha 72, onde existe o seguinte trecho de código:

```
if ($payment->getSender()->getDocuments() != null) {
                $documents = $payment->getSender()->getDocuments();
                if (is_array($documents) && count($documents) == 1) {
                    foreach ($documents as $document) {
                        if (!is_null($document)) {
                            $data['senderCPF'] = $document->getValue(); //essa linha ta errada.. estão ignorando o tipo do documento q vc informa
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

basta alterar por:

```
if ($payment->getSender()->getDocuments() != null) {
                $documents = $payment->getSender()->getDocuments();
                if (is_array($documents) && count($documents) == 1) {
                    foreach ($documents as $document) {
                        if (!is_null($document)) {
                            $data['sender'.$document->getType()] = $document->getValue();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```